# How can I view the 'request' body as JSON-Text as opposed to the JSON parsed into a grid view

Tags: paw-app

JSON gridview crashes when there is a large values like a base64 image.
I can still view the body in text format but it doesn't format the text as expected.
A JSON-text option as there is in the response section would mitigate the issue until the app is capable parsing large values into json.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your JSON view into Text, it will save the data and will render a pretty-printed JSON text.

Edit your JSON:

[image: JSON in Paw]

Switch to Text:

[image: JSON as Text in Paw]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if that's what you were looking for @Hrishikesh Sawant... let me know if you have more details, and I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it
To do this, set the Headers to Content-Type: application/json
[this is what the header looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cvbZ.png)

and use the Text tab for the request body
[this is what the body looks like in json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlueR.png)