# Text-based JSON editor

Tags: paw-app

I have seen [How can I view the 'request' body as JSON-Text as opposed to the JSON parsed into a grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044231/how-can-i-view-the-request-body-as-json-text-as-opposed-to-the-json-parsed-int) but the question and answer feel specific to *viewing* JSON.

Is there a way to enable a text-based JSON editor that I don't know about?

Reasons the plain text mode feels insufficient:

- the `{` character is constantly triggering a drop down that injects variables (I think) and requires hitting `ESC` before starting a new object
  [image: silly key strokes]
- uses non-configurable indentation that doesn't match JSON-text
- no syntax highlighting/validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply this isn't an option yet - you will need to hit escape for those popups. The response panel does have a JSON Text option, so you would imagine something similar for the request panel.

However you should be seeing syntax highlighting, see the screenshot below[image]